# Trying to prevent Javascript from running on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add an onChange event handler to two element of my html page. Sadly the event is firing when the page loads which is causing downstream issues.

```
$("#Division").on('click', onChangeFilter());
$("#Program").change(onChangeFilter());

function onChangeFilter() {
   alert("Fired to soon....");
};
```

The associated HTML for testing looks like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="DivisionSelection">
     <select id="Division" data-filterprogramcontrol="Program">
       <option value="-1">Select Division</option>
       <option value="1">Item 1</option>
       <option value="2">Item 2</option>
       <option value="3">Item 3</option>
     </select>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

Is adding the .change event causing a 'change' and triggering the function? The two closest posts I was able to find are located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6360626/1933427) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17387891/1933427) but I feel their issues were more transparent. Nothing was obvious to me in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/on/) indicating this behavior. I just started transitioning to the web world in my course work, maybe I'm not understanding correctly the dynamics of how a page loads the DOM. I thought [this](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/) page useful but not sure how accurate. Thank you in advance for the guidance.

Comment: Why do you have two elements with the same ID `Division`?

Comment: Remove the invoking parenthesis -- `$("#Division").on('click', onChangeFilter);`. This will pass the function itself as a reference to be invoked later by the event.

Comment: @Xufox, forgot in this example to specify this is a selection Div, updated. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll want to remove the invoking parenthesis after each use of `onChangeFilter`:

```
$("#Division").on('click', onChangeFilter);
//                                      ^^
$("#Program").change(onChangeFilter);
//                                ^^
```

This treats the function as any other (object) value, passing it as an argument to `.on()` and `.change()` for them to use and for the events to invoke when they've been triggered.

Otherwise, with the parenthesis, the function is being called first and its `return` value is instead passed to `.on()` and `.change()`, similar to:

```
var result1 = onChangeFilter();
$("#Division").on('click', result1);

var result2 = onChangeFilter();
$("#Program").change(result2);
```

Comment: thank you for the example and comment above. That does make sense.

Answer (score 2):

When you write like this:

```
$("#Division").on('click', onChangeFilter());
```

you are calling it. The () after method name means you are calling it. Just write the method name there.

The code more-less should be like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var onChangeFilter = function(evt){
           alert("Fired to soon....");
        };
        $("#Division").on('click', onChangeFilter);
        $("#Program").on('change', onChangeFilter);

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="Division">
     <select id="Program">
       <option value="-1">Select Division</option>
       <option value="1">Item 1</option>
       <option value="2">Item 2</option>
       <option value="3">Item 3</option>
     </select>
  </div>    
</body>
</html>
```